# S3ToRedshiftTransfert return 0 element in the table created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, airflow

In this DAG moving data from s3 to redshift, Tasks in the dag are successfully done, but I found no element in the redshift table.
this job needs to be done without boto3.

```
import os
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.hooks.S3_hook import S3Hook
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.s3_to_redshift_operator import S3ToRedshiftTransfer

default_arguments = {'owner': 'airflow', 'start_date': days_ago(1)} 

def list_bucket(bucket_name, prefix, delimiter,**kwargs):
  hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id='s3_default')
  list_objects = hook.list_keys(bucket_name, prefix, delimiter)
  return list_objects


def move_files_from_s3_to_redshift(db, table_, s3_bucket_, copy_options_,task_, **kwargs):

  storage_objects = kwargs["ti"].xcom_pull(task_ids='list_files')
  for storage_object in storage_objects:
    s3_key_ = storage_object
    S3ToRedshiftTransfer(schema=db,
                         table=table_,
                         s3_bucket=s3_bucket_,
                         s3_key=s3_key_,
                         copy_options=copy_options_,
                         task_id=task_)
with DAG('...', task_id= '...' ) as dag :
```

Answer (score 2):

In the code you shared the operator doesn't really run. You only initialized the constructor.

Operator is a Python class. In each operator there is `execute` method which runs the operator logic. Airflow knows to execute this function when you set the operators. However in your example you create an operator inside a Python function.
Airflow doesn't scan inside the function - in the UI you will see a cube of `PythonOperator` and not `S3ToRedshiftTransfer`.

This means that in your code you only called the contractor of `S3ToRedshiftTransfer` but you didn't call the execute method.

You will need to do:

```
    s3_key_ = storage_object
    op = S3ToRedshiftTransfer(schema=db,
                         table=table_,
                         s3_bucket=s3_bucket_,
                         s3_key=s3_key_,
                         copy_options=copy_options_,
                         task_id=task_)
   op.execute()
```

Comment: These functions are executed within the DAG, I just shared functions used by PythonOperator.

Comment: @SaadliIyed as explained. In the code you provided you only call the contractor you did not call execute method thus no logic was executed and the PythonOperator end in success without doing any job.

Comment: @SaadliIyed The `execute` method of S3ToRedshiftTransfer is interacting with S3 & Redshift. In your implementation the method isn't called. There is a diffrance between writing `DAG('...', task_id= '...' ) as dag : S3ToRedshiftTransfer()` - which Airflow automatically call `execute` and doing what you wrote.
You are more than welcome to join the Airflow slack channel for further support.

Comment: @SaadliIyed I think Elad is right and maybe simply try it ;)

Comment: I think you right I still trying I always get this error:  ERROR - could not connect to server: No such file or directory 
I passed SQL query  to op.execute(sql) 
sql = """
                        copy public.lc_logisticcompany 
                        from 's3://airflowbuckettest/{}' 
                        credentials 'aws_access_key_id=ID;aws_secret_access_key=KEY 
                        csv IGNOREHEADER 1
                        """.format(s3_key_)